# Unable to use else if in onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-fragments, if-statement, conditional-statements, onactivityresult

For the simplicity below is my code in `onActivityResult` method inside `fragment`

```
  if (requestCode==ADD_ADDRESS_REQUEST_CODE){
        // do something
    }else if (requestCode==COUNTRIES_REQUEST_CODE){
        // do something
    }
```

But on the `else if` statement `Android Studio` says

> Condition requestCode==COUNTRIES_REQUEST_CODE is always false

I have more than one results in my `Fragment` so I have to check them based on the request code putting `else if` statements the situation is as discussed above.
If I use only `if` statements like

```
if (requestCode==ADD_ADDRESS_REQUEST_CODE){
        // do something
    }
  if (requestCode==COUNTRIES_REQUEST_CODE){
        // do something
    }
```

The first condition is always true even if the request code for that is not yet set. `ADD_ADDRESS_REQUEST_CODE` would be set when a button in `fragment` will be pressed and the `COUNTRIES_REQUEST_CODE` is set on `onCreateView` method of the fragment. So when Fragment shows its `GUI` a `toast` is showing that is inside of first condition.

Can anybody explain a bit why is that and how can I fix it. Any effort will be appreciated.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem using Android Studio 3.0.1 and a `Fragment` with `onActivityResult()` containing your code snippet, with `private static final int` declarations for your two constants. I suggest that you edit your question with a complete fragment that reproduces your issue.

Comment: What are the values of `ADD_ADDRESS_REQUEST_CODE` and `COUNTRIES_REQUEST_CODE`?

Comment: @MikeM. thanks for pointing the issue, that both had the same value now its well with different value.

Comment: thanks guys @CommonsWare and MikeM for your time.